# How can we implement a hover effect on navigation rail in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I am building a flutter application for web and desktop. I have used navigation rail for routing, but i can't figure out how to add a hover effect when the mouse is over a particular rail destination. There is a property to change the color depending upon which rail is being selected but i want to have a hover effect for the rail as well. How can i achieve this in flutter ?

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Are you looking for something like `page preview`? I can't completely undestand what is hover effect, which u want to achieve, some `GIF` would be really suitable here

Comment: this might be helpful : https://medium.com/flutter-community/hover-effects-in-flutter-web-using-extensions-2eb262bb6309

Answer (score 0):

You should use Drawer widget, in that there is a hover effect you can apply.